# Repositioning the alert dialog on Android

Tags: android

I'm unable to resize and reposition the alert dialog box. Please help me do this!

Answer (score 1):

I think not possible since the api does not support it.

You should write your own class that extends the dialog or create an activity and use [android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen) to make it look like a dialog.
Then you can use standard techniques for placing widgets.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried, Now, I can reposition the AlertDialog, but I can not resize it.

```
    Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Sample Title");
    AlertDialog d = builder.create();
    Window win = d.getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = win.getAttributes();
    lp.y = 100;
    lp.width = 320; //It does not work.
    win.setAttributes(lp);
    d.show();
```